# Changing the \sum symbol in fraction

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

I would like my \sum symbol to appear like on the right side of the equation (n on top and i on the bottom) rather than be on the side, however when I use \frac, the shape of \sum changes as I tried to display in the image. How can I force the sum symbols in the fraction to appear like the on the right?

```
\begin{align}
{\color{dca}\sigma(a_k,b_k)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ki - \overline{a_k})(b_ki - \overline{b_k})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ki - \overline{a_k})^2(b_ki - \overline{b_k})^2}} 
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code does not match the output, but only a part of it. Also, please always provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You can write probably use `\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n}{x}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I don't know what `\color{dca}` is, I replaced it with `IndianRed` (from `svgnames`). Here is a simple solution:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    {\color{IndianRed}\sigma(a_k,b_k)} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_ki - \overline{a_k})(b_ki - \overline{b_k})}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a_ki - \overline{a_k})^2(b_ki - \overline{b_k})^2}}
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]